# How to add font family to svg being used within <img>

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 300 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
        <style type="text/css">
            /* SVG Style */
            @font-face {font-family: "Bebas";
              src: url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.eot"); /* IE9*/
              src: url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
              url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome、firefox */
              url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome、firefox */
              url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome、firefox、opera、Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
              url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.svg#Century Gothic Bold V1") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
            }
    .text{
          font-family: 'Bebas' !important;
        }
        </style>
        <text class="text" id="S" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-size="100" font-weight="bold" fill="#FF4B00">
                    <tspan x="100" y="100">S</tspan>
                </text>
                <text class="text" id="S-Copy" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-size="100" font-weight="bold" fill="#FF4B00">
                    <tspan x="100" y="150">S</tspan>
                </text></svg>
```

I have an svg with embedded styles and I am using it on my main page as

`<img src="images/test.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/test.png'">`

SVG:

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 300 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* SVG Style */
        @font-face {font-family: "Bebas";
          src: url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.eot"); /* IE9*/
          src: url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
          url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome、firefox */
          url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome、firefox */
          url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome、firefox、opera、Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
          url("../fonts/7bea0c92e559e23f9bd920d83612b1db.svg#Century Gothic Bold V1") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
        }
.text{
      font-family: 'Bebas' !important;
    }
    </style>
    <text class="text" id="S" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-size="100" font-weight="bold" fill="#FF4B00">
                <tspan x="100" y="100">S</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="text" id="S-Copy" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-size="100" font-weight="bold" fill="#FF4B00">
                <tspan x="100" y="150">S</tspan>
            </text></svg>
```

I am using `font-family: "Bebas"` on `.text`.

Everything works fine when I access the image as `http://localhost/test/images/test.svg`

But when it is accessed on the main page i.e on `http://localhost/test/index.php`, the font style is not applied.

I also referred [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/) for the scope of css styling in svg.

How can I make it work on my main page?

Comment: Just to make it work for now, I have converted `<text class='.text'... ` to line object in sketch, But I am curious to understand why it is not working

Comment: You'd have to convert all the external font files to data urls and embed them in the SVG file. SVG as an image must be complete in a single file.

Comment: So I have to use it something like `src: url("....DataURL....") format("woff");`?

Comment: you need the mime type etc too per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: @RobertLongson So its going to be a long long string with jumbled words =)

Comment: That's right. They are binary files anyway so converting them to base64 isn't going to make them any worse.